# Using switch and $_GET

Tags: php

I'm creating a mega menu for a clothing e-commerce site. The categories are split between **New In**, **Women** and **Men**.  **New In** will just be links straight to particular products but I want the **Women** and **Men** categories to be linked to the relevant categories via just two pages. So underneath the **Women** category will be skirts and tops for example.

My code is starts off as...

```
$ItemCategory = ['$category'];
$category = "";

switch ($_GET['$category']) {
    case "Women";
    // the difference in variables go here;
    break;

    case "Men";
    // the difference in variables go here;
    break;
}
```

I don't know if I'm going about this the right way or what way to approach it.  Obviously the bit where the comment is would be where I would enter each category.  Although I'm not sure what would go here.

Also, what would the link be for skirts for example? Would it be

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/store.php?gender=Women&category=skirts">Skirts</a>
```

Or am I totally missing the point?

Comment: Can you give us your correct your code ? `$ItemCategory = ['$category']` => `$_GET['category']` Maybe ? same near `switch` statement. Also, if `category=skirts` it can not match with "Women" nor "Men"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That needs a combined switch or an if-else:

```
$ItemCategory = $_GET['category'];
$gender = $_GET['gender'];

if($gender == 'Women'){
    switch ($ItemCategory) {
        case "Skirts":
        // content
        break;

        case "Hats":
        // content
        break;
    }
}else if($gender == 'Men'){
    switch ($ItemCategory) {
        case "Ties":
        // content
        break;

        case "Trousers":
        // content
        break;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to store the categories in the database (which you probably do anyways) and define which category belongs to men and women. Then you could only use a single category id to navigate.

Comment: Hi Martin, what would go in the '//content' area.  Would it be the URL?

Comment: Well I thought you got URLs from the eshop system like in your question. You must work with what you got after all. The case just contains the queries or whatever you do process after you know which case you are working with (for example woman skirts).

Comment: Right ok, so the URL should go in there?  Sorry, as I mentioned, I've never used switch before.

Comment: if you want to redirect via the url then you should generate it there, yes.  switch is just a better way to have less code when dealing with many options. you could rewrite each switch into many if/elseif statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ItemCategory = $_GET['category'];
$category = "";

switch ($ItemCategory) {
    case "Women":
    // the difference in variables go here;
    break;

    case "Men":
    // the difference in variables go here;
    break;
}
```